# would it be possible in theory to re-activate the Spitzer telescope?

Tags: spitzer-space-telescope

since it's purposeful deactivation in 2020, the Spitzer Space Telescope has been floating aimlessly, doomed to wander through its orbital path uselessly doing nothing for a (possibly eternal) amount of time. But I wonder, maybe, if we really wanted to, we could turn it back on. You see, the spacecraft was not put into a "Permanent unrecoverable" sleep mode unlike its relative, Kepler (which was commanded to turn off its transmitters and stop listening for commands from earth). Spitzer was placed in a "Yes-I'm-in-sleep-mode-but-I'm-still-here-and-listening-just-not-doing-any-science" mode. Also, Spitzer was placed in a position that placed its solar arrays towards the sun, so the batteries are probably fine. Another reason it might still be salvageable is that every so often Spitzer sends a "Yes, I'm still alive" message, even though no one is listening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR:

In theory yes, but not worth it for the amount of realistic science time the platform has left to operate in real terms.

Further:

> Also, Spitzer was placed in a position that placed its solar arrays towards the sun, so the batteries are probably fine.

Not so, as you can read below - communicating with Earth and being recharged by the sun via its panels worked for its early years in an orbit that was closer to the Earth. As time has gone on, that distance from Earth increased and the panels now face further away from the sun than they were ever designed to do. Spitzer had to have its programming modified so that it did not shut down at the (out of design spec) angles it now operates at. Communication with Earth and recharging from the sun are now not possible at the same time.

> The spacecraft radio antenna is not steerable, so pointing in the daily data dumps is done by slewing the entire telescope.

From Don Barry, Spitzer Space Telescope IRS Instrument Team, Cornell University:

> There is no propulsion capability on the spacecraft other than a quite limited dry-nitrogen system intended for occasional angular momentum dumps off the reaction wheels, so there was no intent to "aim" it anywhere except in a low-precision trajectory.

Spitzer, in the mode it is in now, is at a fixed attitude, it will not be compensating for its orbit around the sun, in order to keep facing it and recharging. Due in part to this, at some point it will just fail. Mind you, in around 60 years it should come within reach of Earth again.

> NASA scientists will send a command to Spitzer, telling it to stop taking observations and no longer send pings back to Earth. Conceivably, **NASA could wake Spitzer back up again someday**, but as more time passes, the tougher that will be. Spitzer will **no longer be pointing its antenna back at Earth** and sending a strong signal that NASA can pick up. So making a link with the spacecraft will become harder and harder.

Just using links from the Wikipedia article:

[image]

> "According to (Michael, Project Scientist for Spitzer at JPL) Werner, there were no technical limitations preventing Spitzer from continuing observations for at least another year. Instead, NASA retired Spitzer so its resources could be allocated to the agency’s next generation infrared observatory, the JWST" -

So in theory yes, reactivation possible but time is limited:

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ending-in-2020-nasas-infrared-spitzer-mission-leaves-a-gap-in-astronomy/?redirect=1

> It is slowly moving away from our planet in its Earth-trailing orbit, requiring Spitzer to pitch at higher angles to beam its transmissions home and reducing the amount of sunlight striking the spacecraft’s solar panels. Where once it could transmit indefinitely, it can now manage just two and a half hours a day before its batteries drain.

> "As the angle between the Earth, the sun and the telescope changes, (it) makes it more difficult to simultaneously keep the solar panels pointed at the sun, to keep the communications antenna pointed at the Earth, to keep the telescope pointed at the stars and planets we want to look at, and to keep the sun off of the telescope so that it stays very cold and is able to continue its infrared (observations),"

Spitzer is moving away from Earth in its orbit and it is increasingly having to pitch beyond designed angles with which to communicate with Earth. The same angles turn it away from the sun so its communication time is increasingly limited by the need to recharge, to a point where the latter would outrank the need for the former, just to keep operating. The value of science returns were seen as diminishing the longer the project went on and the risk of a serious mission-ending problem arising was increasing.

> “We are retiring it because of increasingly difficult and risky operations, which is reducing the science value of the mission.

https://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/news/ssc2019-10-how-nasas-spitzer-has-stayed-alive-for-so-long

> Entering safe mode can be particularly hazardous for the spacecraft, both because of its growing distance from Earth (which makes communicating more difficult) and because the aging onboard systems might not restart once they shut off.

> as Spitzer ages and gets farther from Earth, the challenge of keeping the spacecraft operating and the risk that it will suffer a major anomaly are only increasing.

https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/30/21111895/nasa-spitzer-space-telescope-end-of-mission-infrared-trappist

https://www.wired.com/story/rip-spitzer-telescope/

https://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/news/ssc2020-08-nasas-spitzer-space-telescope-ends-mission-of-astronomical-discovery

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/spitzer-space-telescope-shut-down-by-nasa/